# Order By two columns but have one order

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

This question is sequelize specific but I'd figure if I found a way to do in SQL then I could find a way to do it in sequelize

I need for the request to be ordered back by `user.fullname` which is joined by using `include` and by `mockUser.fullname` which is a  JSON field.

One important thing to keep in mind however is that `user` is nullable in the case a `mockUser` is present.

This is what I have so far, it is ordering by `mockUser.fullname` and `user.fullname`, However, it is doing so separately, meaning there are two correct orders but they're not ordered into one single order which is the desired result.

```js
      const options = {
        where: args,
        include: ['user'],
        limit,
        offset,
        order: [['user', 'fullname', 'ASC'], ['mockUser.fullname', 'ASC']]
      }
```

SQL equivalent-ish of the above sequelize representation, it's spit out by sequelize but I cleaned it up

**Note: it turns every "user"."column" as "user.column"**

```sql
SELECT * FROM "table" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "user" ON "table"."userId" = "user"."id" 
WHERE "table"."columnId" = '9efcbd5a-4dc7-4102-ad59-b6f6cd9adaa4'
ORDER BY "user"."fullname" ASC, ("table"."mockUser"#>>'{fullname}') ASC 
LIMIT 10 
OFFSET 0;
```

*I'm using `table` and `column` to obfuscate the real names*

Example output:

```
Adam Smith -> user
Beatrice Westfield -> user
John Smith -> user
Andy Brook -> mockUser
Mario Jimenez -> mockUser
Nadia Martinez -> mockUser
```

Desired Output:

```
Adam Smith -> user
Andy Brook -> mockUser
Beatrice Westfield -> user
John Smith -> user
Mario Jimenez -> mockUser
Nadia Martinez -> mockUser
```

As you can see it first sorts user and then mockUser, but how could I combine both?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to show the output you want? "how could I combine both?" isn't quite clear.

Comment: My bad you're right, I have added the desired output to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
order by coalesce (user, mockUser)
```

in this case if user is null it will order by mockuser.

Comment: That might just work, just need to test it with sequelize